# How to generate a random number in the entire binary64 range

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am wondering how to generate a random double number inside the entire double range in Python, so that the order of magnitude of the number (`math.log10`) has an equal chance to be any of the possible magnitudes (`range(-307, 309)`).

I tried the following code but it does not give intended result:

```py
from random import random, uniform
from collections import Counter
import math
import sys

random_numbers = [random()/random() for i in range(2048)]

count = Counter([int(math.log10(i)) for i in random_numbers])

print(count.most_common())

uniform_numbers = [uniform(sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.max) for i in range(2048)]

count1 = Counter([int(math.log10(i)) for i in uniform_numbers])

print(count1.most_common())
```

```
[(0, 1862), (1, 93), (-1, 68), (2, 14), (-2, 10), (3, 1)] 
[(307, 1055), (308, 888), (306, 95), (305, 10)]
```

Comment: Generate a number between -307 and 309 based on a uniform distribution, then compute its exponential

Comment: @MateoVial Could you please elaborate that in an answer?

Comment: It's very late in my locale, I am going to sleep now, so I will not be able to respond to the interactions in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because logarithm and exponential are inverse functions of eachother, you can do that by generating a number along a uniform distribution, and then compute its exponential

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
x = 10 ** np.random.uniform(low=-307, high=309, size=N)
```

keep in mind that the resulting distribution will not be uniform (because it is "distorted" by the exponential). Very often, the sample will be very close to 0 or very close to infinity.

Comment: I believe it is better to do this: `x = 2 ** np.random.uniform(low=-1022, high=1024, size=2048)`, your code causes overflows, change the numbers and I will accept your answer.

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't seem to overflow for me, both ways behave the same way (I don't know what do you mean by _overflow_ since we're working with floats). Plus, doing that would be incoherent with your question. If you modify your question, i'd greatly modify my answer